# Mapping cases in web.xml

Tags: java, xml, web-applications, web.xml, url-mapping

In `web.xml`, is it possible to have a main mapping and a second mapping used with mappings that are different from the first one as shown below?

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/?</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Wicpar, thanks for editing

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple `servlet-mapping`s in a deployment descriptor. The rules for selecting a mapping are described in the [Java Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-mrel-spec.pdf) Chapter 12. Mapping Requests to Servlets:

> 12.1 Use of URL Paths
>   ...
>   The path used for mapping to a servlet is the request URL from the request object minus the context path and the path parameters. The URL path mapping rules below are used in order. The first successful match is used with no further matches attempted:
>
> 1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the path of the servlet. A successful match selects the servlet.
> 2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done by stepping down the path tree a directory at a time, using the ’/’ character as a path separator. The longest match determines the servlet selected.
> 3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), the servlet container will try to match a servlet that handles requests for the extension. An extension is defined as the part of the last segment after the last ’.’ character.
> 4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will attempt to serve content appropriate for the resource requested. If a "default" servlet is defined for the application, it will be used. Many containers provide an implicit default servlet for serving content.

So this means, if you have an exact match like `<url-pattern>/tar</url-pattern>`, this mapping will be selected. Otherwise the second, less specific mapping, (e.g. `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`) will be used.

But you *cannot* create a mapping with `<url-pattern>/tar*</url-pattern>`, because an asterisk is only allowed at the end `/*` or at the beginning `*.` of a pattern (note the slash `/` before and the period `.` after the asterisk). See section 12.2 Specification of Mappings for the full details.

Comment: The idea was that we know first mapping exactly, for example `/tar`, but we do not know the other possible mappins `/targe`, `/targ` and so on... So Second Servlet should process all mappings which are different from the `/tar` pattern.